# How to stop a Vibe.D application?

Tags: exception, d, terminate, vibed

Does Vibe.D have a build-in terminate function, for when the library is run through a static initializer? I want to terminate the application when vibe.d throws an exception when for example opening a file.

I have a server listening using the `listenHTTP` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `getEventDriver().exitEventLoop();`, from [here](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.core.driver/getEventDriver) and [here](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.core.driver/EventDriver.exitEventLoop).

EDIT: There's a simpler version, the standalone function [`vibe.core.core.exitEventLoop`](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.core.core/exitEventLoop).

Comment: Does the `listenHTTP` function start an Event Loop?

Comment: No, it happens automatically in [`vibe.appmain`](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/blob/master/source/vibe/appmain.d), see the `runEventLoop()` call.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the Event Loop relates to the `listenHTTP`. I'm not using `vibeappmain`. When I call `listenHTTP` inside the static constructor, my code runs fine and the HTTP Requests get handled. No event loop getting started. (Unless internally by `listenHTTP`, but if I put it inside the main method the program stops automatically unless I manually call `renEventLoop()`.

Comment: I see, without a main method it uses the vibe.d default one. Thanks.